# how to upgrade php 5.3 to php 7.2 in redhat 6.8

Tags: php, upgrade, redhat

I currently have php53 installed redhat version 6.8

```
rh@StorServIN ~]$ php -v
PHP Warning:  Module 'pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Dec 15 2015 04:52:58)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
[rh@StorServIN ~]$ php -v
PHP Warning:  Module 'pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Dec 15 2015 04:52:58)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

how to upgrading my php 5.3 to latest php (7.2) in redhat,
i already search in google for this case, but not work for me,
anyone can give me best solution for my problem?

Comment: This didn't work: sudo yum install php72 ?

Comment: Thank you for answering, after all my instructions have followed, there are some who have not succeeded, whether you can give correct instructions

Comment: Since RHEL is binary source safe, the default libraries available to it are limited. You will need to install and use Remi, IUS, or SCL repositories for the desired library packages.

Comment: well i will try it

Comment: this is the right repo? http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm

Comment: You have `release-6`, As in `RHEL 6.x` Follow https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/ Remi is a simple way since, it is a drop in replacement. However you will need to swap out your `/etc/php.d/*.ini` and `/etc/php.ini` config files with the `*.rpmnew` changes

Comment: by the way, what if I want to use the old php.ini configuration, not the new one? cause i make proxy in my server

Comment: @fyrye That sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: @HenryGunawan make a custom ini file in `/etc/php.d` called `9999-custom.ini` and add all of your custom configurations there. This will preserve the changes from updates in the future and your own custom settings. As well as make troubleshooting those settings easier. PHP will scan the `/etc/php.d` directory and include all of the `.ini` files it finds, loading them alphabetically.

Comment: @user3783243 true, however it is technically my opinion to use those packages, there are others. I would expand into each different method of REMI, IUS and SCL, but that is more of a tutorial piece on how to acquire and install third-party software as opposed to an answer related to programming.

Comment: @fyrye There maybe alternatives, but from reading of the comments it sounds like this works (which to me is an answer) ... or maybe this should be on serverfault?

Comment: @user3783243 either on serverfault or closed as off-topic (tutorial, software library, or other off-site resource).

Comment: guys, now when i try to yum install, error : yum fail with an error that a repo is listed more than once?
how i can fix it? thanks